# Tesseract (tess-two) recognising symbols and retraining dataset for a few characters?

Tags: dataset, ocr, tesseract, training-data, tess-two

Sorry for bothering you but I'm just a beginner with tess-two.
The question I want to ask is I have been trying to figure out the characters/symbols that are included in the eng.traineddata but haven't been able to find it. Could anyone guide me in the correct way?

Also, I am using the tess-two for Android and I've built the tess-two library natively. I'm working on a project that uses a dataset which recognises the following symbols and I'm assuming that the eng.traineddata has them :

£, ¥, $ etc.

I've been successfully been able to recognise the Euro and the dollar symbol but the recognition fails when I add the other symbols to the whitelist. Is it because the dataset has not been trained on these characters or there is something wrong with the input image?

Also, please do let me know if there are any other traineddata files that contain all these symbols, would be of great help.

Thanks